# Python Amazon SQS

Tags: python, memory-leaks, amazon-sqs

I am using amazon sqs for sending message with python.
I am sending RawMessage with body base 64 encoded.
I am checking that the message is less than 262144 bytes but I am still getting error that the message is larger than 262144 bytes and even more important
I see that after each sending failure my program memory is increased.

```
zippedMessage = newMessage.encode("zlib")
base64MSG = base64.b64encode(zippedMessage)
currentMsgSize = len(base64MSG)

if currentMsgSize < 262144:
   messageToSend = RawMessage()
   messageToSend.set_body(base64MSG)
   queue.write(message)
else:
   #I split the message to smaller pices
```

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Give us more detail. Paste some code. Paste a traceback. How are you checking the length? What is the length of the message that you got?

Comment: example code  zippedMessage = newMessage.encode("zlib")
            base64MSG = base64.b64encode(zippedMessage)
   currentMsgSize = len(base64MSG)
   
   if currentMsgSize < 262144:
    messageToSend = RawMessage()
    messageToSend.set_body(base64MSG)
    self.queue.write(message)
   else:
   #I split the message to smaller pices

Comment: zippedMessage = newMessage.encode("zlib")
            base64MSG = base64.b64encode(zippedMessage)
   currentMsgSize = len(base64MSG)
   
   if currentMsgSize < 262144:
    messageToSend = RawMessage()
    messageToSend.set_body(base64MSG)
    self.queue.write(message)
   else:
   #I split the message to smaller pices

Comment: Please paste a traceback and also add a `print currentMsgSize` and tell us what value you get, as I asked. Also add `print get_queue_attributes(queue, attribute='MaximumMessageSize')` and show us the output.